# Nuxt js npm error No command specified

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, webstorm

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть сайт на nuxt js в который необходимо изредка вносить мелкие поправки. В очередной раз при попытке запустить проект в девелопмент режиме - появляется ошибка  ERROR  No command specified.

Запускаю через npm run dev[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка после запуска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог ответ в [этом топике](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864622/nuxt-command-not-found-having-to-use-npx-instead-of-npm). У меня в `node_modules/nuxt/bin` содержится файл `nuxt.mjs`, и команда:

```
./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js dev
```

успешно разворачивает проект на `localhost:3000`.